# Grails 5 how can I install the fields-templates

Tags: grails, gsp

Grails 5 is using the fields-plugin (as stated in the scaffolding plugin and I see it in the Intellij-IDEA Grails-View of my project under **plugins**).

[image]

But how can I install the fields-plugin templates?

Even in the GitHub-sources I could only find the templates for _embedded, _list and _table.

what am I missing?

(The reason for all that is, that I want to know, how the inList constraint is handled in a g:select. I know it's working, but if I try it the "old-fashioned" way with

```
from=${MyDomain.constraints.myField.inList}
```

grails throws errors `Cannot get property 'myField' on null object`

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but the delivered plugin has no other template files as the mentioned ones, the base "template" is done through the taglib and you can override with "self-made" tag-gsps in views.

But I would like to see some documentation, which variables you could use in own template-files... or did I miss it?

The **constraints** attribute has changed to **constrainedProperties**.